# What is the quickest way to print Binary permutation?

Tags: java, binary, permutation

If n=3 and r=2, print below

```
110
101
011
```

I'm using below code, But it takes a long time.

```
public void printBinaryPermutation(int n, int r)
{
    for(BigInteger i = new BigInteger("0"); i.compareTo(BigInteger.TWO.pow(n)) == -1; i = i.add(BigInteger.ONE))
    {
        String str = i.toString(2);
        while(str.length() < n)
        {
            str = "0" + str;
        }
        BigInteger amount = new BigInteger("0");
        for(char c : str.toCharArray())
        {
            if(c == '1')
            {
                amount = amount.add(BigInteger.ONE);
            }
        }
        if(amount.compareTo(new BigInteger(String.valueOf(r))) == 0)
        {
            System.out.println(str);
        }
    }
}
```

What is the quickest way to print Binary permutation?

Comment: The quickest way would be to precompute them and then printing them would be almost instantly. Surely you want to know how to *calculate* them more quickly?

Comment: I'd use recursion.  Take the output from `printBinaryPermutation(n-1,r)` and append `0` to everything; then take the output from `printBinaryPermutation(n-1,r-1)` and append `1` to everything.  I'm pretty sure that's not the quickest way, but it will be FAR quicker than what you're doing here.